# Octave: xlsread - warning: UnZip failed with error 9

Tags: octave

I am trying to run xls read on octave and after installing all the packages ( io, symbolic, window etc.)
When I tried to run

`xlsread('file.xlsm','Sheet'`)

It shows this error :

> Unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of the file.xlsm or
>   file.xlsm.zip Warning: Unzip failed with error 9

Comment: are you sure it's a valid xlsm? Can libreoffice open it?

Comment: Yes, I am able to open it on MSExcel

Comment: I asked if you could open it in another software than "MSExcel". And I think the only way for someone to help you is if you upload it so others can try. Also add the used operating system, version of GNU Octave and version of io package

Answer (score 0):

same thing happened to me,
in my case it was caused by access rights protection in excel (e.g. read-only, or locked for modifications)